# config.cache_classes=true only for certian domains in production mode in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I would like to use `config.cache_classes = true` on www.cybercellar.com and `config.cache_classes = false` on dev2013.cybercellar.com How would I go about this? both are running in production mode.

I tried this in my /app/config/enviroments/production.rb but to no avail

```
  if  == "www.cybercellar.com"
      config.cache_classes = true
  else
      config.cache_classes = false
  end
```

but i got this error

```
undefined local variable or method `request' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Comment: The request object is not accessible from a config file. There's no HTTP request when starting the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new environment like production. Steps are,

1 . Add new environment in config/database.yml, the name like Sandbox.
2 . Create sandbox.rb under config/enviroments/. Here load your settings based on domains or anything.

Comment: sounds good, but how do I tell the app to use this enviroment when I visit dev2013.cybercellar.com ?

Comment: You need 2 server instances. One started with 'production' environment, and the other one with 'sandbox' environment.

Comment: We need to configure the server to run in sandbox mode. If you are running the server using apache, you should specify the RailsEnv sandbox in virtual host setup.

Comment: I do this for my staging env and it works great. I have a shared-env.rb file that gets required in both production.rb and staging.rb, and then have any unique settings in those files.